# Grab images from JSON file with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, electron

I am testing an Electron app. I want it to grab images from [this](http://www.pgbovine.net/json-photo-gallery.htm) website. That website has a JSON file that has [this](http://www.pgbovine.net/photos/json-files/boston.json) code.

How can I get those images and put them in an img tag?

So far I have this code:

```
var request = require('request');

request("http://www.pgbovine.net/photos/json-files/boston.json" ,     function(error, response, body) {
body = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(body);

function addImg(arr) {
   myImg = arr[0]["filename"];
   var theImg = document.getElementById("image");

   theImg.innerHTML = myImg;
}
```

And this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pics</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <img id="image">

    <script type="text/javascript">
      require("./memes.js")
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is, that code doesn't do anything! So how can I grab an image from the JSON file above and put it into and img tag? (Using NodeJS or vanilla JavaScript)

Comment: Where you are using the js code ? Is the js code used in the main javascript application file ? "that code doesn't do anything" is a poor description. Post your package.json and the main.js file of your app.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply adding to the `img` tag the filename, but you need to add the entire image url not just the filename (like IMG_2914.JPG).

I tried http://www.pgbovine.net/photos/IMG_2914.JPG but got 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

You should be modifying the 'src' attribute of the img html tag to point to the URL or relative path of the image in question.

You would call the 'setAttribute' method on `theImg`variable to do this.

Based of the structure of that JSON response, you may also want to set the 'alt' attribtue to the 'description' string of each image object, which would provide a simple mouse-over text.

Note that the JSON that you're talking about here doesn't actually contain the image, just a string that is the filename of the image.

Based on the website you seem to be attempting to scrape, to grab things from the boston image gallery, you would need to append the filename to the following string:
`http://www.pgbovine.net/new-galleries/boston/images/`

Like so:

`<img src="http://www.pgbovine.net/new-galleries/boston/images/IMG_2914.JPG">`